# Explicitly set sequence of vectors in paste -function

Tags: r

Say I wanted to add a minus sign `-` in front of all values in both columns of a data.frame `datasets::cars` using `apply`:

```
> apply(cars[1:5,], 2, paste0, "-")
      speed dist 
  [1,] "4-"  "2-" 
  [2,] "4-"  "10-"
  [3,] "7-"  "4-" 
  [4,] "7-"  "22-"
  [5,] "8-"  "16-"
```

Note, that here the minus is *behind* the numbers not in front. So I came up with the following which gives the desired output:

```
> apply(cars[1:5,], 2, function(x) paste0("-", x))
        speed dist 
   [1,] "-4"  "-2" 
   [2,] "-4"  "-10"
   [3,] "-7"  "-4" 
   [4,] "-7"  "-22"
   [5,] "-8"  "-16"
```

However, this got me wondering: Is there a way to directly specify the position of the minus or, conversely, the position of the margin values in the `paste` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax of `paste0` is `paste0(..., collapse = NULL)`. I.e it takes arguments in the order of their appearance and pastes together. The syntax of `apply` is `apply(X, MARGIN, FUN, ...)`, where `...` stands for additional arguments, that are passed to `paste0` after the subsetted element from `X` on positions 2, 3 and so on. Because apply passes `x` always in first place there is no way around the anonymous fucntion.
I.e. the argument must be `FUN = function(x) paste0("-", x)` to force `paste0` to put the "-" first.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using some regex

```
> sapply(cars[1:5,], function(x) sub("(.*)", "-\\1", x))  # infront
     speed dist 
[1,] "-4"  "-2" 
[2,] "-4"  "-10"
[3,] "-7"  "-4" 
[4,] "-7"  "-22"
[5,] "-8"  "-16"
> sapply(cars[1:5,], function(x) sub("(.*)", "\\1-", x))  # behind
     speed dist 
[1,] "4-"  "2-" 
[2,] "4-"  "10-"
[3,] "7-"  "4-" 
[4,] "7-"  "22-"
[5,] "8-"  "16-"
> sapply(cars[1:5,], function(x) sub("(.{1})(.*)", "\\1-\\2", x))  # between
     speed dist 
[1,] "4-"  "2-" 
[2,] "4-"  "1-0"
[3,] "7-"  "4-" 
[4,] "7-"  "2-2"
[5,] "8-"  "1-6"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's a nice work around! However, I already had a working solution using a different function and wanted to know if there was a way exclusively using `paste`.